# Boost Serialization Compile Errors, terribly confused

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

Okay so basically :

i have this simple example:

main.cpp

```
using namespace VHGO::Resource;

std::list<BaseTable*> tableList;

BigTable* bt1 = new BigTable();
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
hr = bt1->Add(L"TEXTURE", L"..\\Data\\ground.png");
tableList.push_back(bt1);

std::wofstream ofs3(L"VHGOSatData.bif");
boost::archive::xml_woarchive outArch3(ofs3);
outArch3 & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(tableList);
```

And my serialization classes

```
namespace VHGO
{
 typedef std::wstring String;
 typedef std::map<VHGO::String, VHGO::String> PropertyMap;
    namespace Resource
    {
        class BaseTable
        {
            friend class boost::serialization::access;
            friend std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& os, const BaseTable& b );
        private:
            template<class Archive>
            void save(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) const {}

            template<class Archive>
            void load(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {}
        public:
            BaseTable()
            {
            }
            //for boost
            virtual ~BaseTable()
            {
            }

            virtual HRESULT Add(__in const VHGO::String&, __in const VHGO::String&) = 0;
            virtual HRESULT Remove(__in const VHGO::String&) = 0;
            virtual HRESULT Get(__in const VHGO::String&, __out VHGO::String&) = 0;
        };

        std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& os, const BaseTable& b )
        {
            UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(b);
            return os;
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        class BigTable : public BaseTable
        {
            friend class boost::serialization::access;

        private:
            VHGO::PropertyMap m_Values;
            template<class Archive>
            void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
            {
                boost::serialization::split_member(ar, *this, version);
            }


            template<class Archive>
            void save(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) const
            {
                UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(version);
                ar << boost::serialization::base_object<const VHGO::Resource::BaseTable>(*this);
                ar << boost::serialization::make_nvp("bigtable", m_Values);

            }

            template<class Archive>
            void load(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
            {
                UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(version);
                ar >> boost::serialization::base_object<BaseTable>(*this);
                ar >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("bigtable", m_Values);
            }

           // BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()

        public:
            BigTable(__in const VHGO::PropertyMap& propMap)
                : m_Values(propMap)
            {

            }

            BigTable()
            {

            }

            virtual ~BigTable()
            {

            }
            HRESULT Add(__in const VHGO::String& propKey, __in const VHGO::String& propValue)
            {
               //itadds

      return S_OK;
            }

            HRESULT Remove(__in const VHGO::String& propKey)
            {
                /*insertchecking*/
                return S_OK;
            }

            HRESULT Get(__in const VHGO::String& key, __out VHGO::String& aValue)
            {
                aValue = m_Values[key];
                return S_OK;
            }

            VHGO::PropertyMap GetPropertyMap()
            {
                return m_Values;
            }
        };
```

What is the cause of this, ive gone through the documents, and i can make boost's examples work fine. But i cannot make this work. Ive searched around, several times and found mixed results. But i am pretty much in the dark,.

The compile error is this:

```
Error 1 error C2664: 'boost::mpl::assertion_failed' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::mpl::failed ************boost::serialization::is_wrapper<T>::* ***********' to 'boost::mpl::assert<false>::type'
```

im using VC9.0, and using boost 1.41.

Does anyone have any ideas?

*EDIT*

Added the wrapper as suggested

namespace boost { 
    namespace serialization {
        template<>
        struct is_wrapper
            : mpl::true_
        {};
    } // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost

Still leads to the following error

```
1>d:\wrkspace\Sources\External\boost\boost/archive/basic_xml_oarchive.hpp(87) : error C2664: 'boost::mpl::assertion_failed' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::mpl::failed ************boost::serialization::is_wrapper<T>::* ***********' to 'boost::mpl::assert<false>::type'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=const std::list<VHGO::Resource::BaseTable *>
1>        ]
1>        No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>        d:\wrkspace\Sources\External\boost\boost/archive/detail/interface_oarchive.hpp(64) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::basic_xml_oarchive<Archive>::save_override<T>(T &,int)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Archive=boost::archive::xml_woarchive,
1>            T=std::list<VHGO::Resource::BaseTable *>
1>        ]
```

*EDIT 2*

I caved and tried this on gcc, and it works fine. Sadily, i absolutely need it to work on VS2008 which is the standard at work.

Comment: Did you look at boost's source code around the failed assertion?  When I had an assertion in boost' serialization library there was a nice comment that explained what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Sadily there doesnt seem to be anything of value. :(

I am honesltly about to go insane.

Comment: It sounds like this part of boost just doesn't work w/ your compiler.  Try the boost mailing list?  You could also try the latest (or even a development) version if you haven't already.

Comment: If you're desperate, delete the compile-time assertion from the boost code.  Presumably you're not violating an assertion :)

Comment: Tried that, results in terrible crash.

I ended up just doing sloppy coding to deal with this :(

Comment: Does this mean there are no way to serialize pointers of different type under VS2008 using boost serialization ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try, from the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/serialization/doc/traits.html):

> When serializing an object through a
>   pointer to its base class, the library
>   needs to determine whether or not the
>   base is abstract (i.e. has at least
>   one virtual function). The library
>   uses the type trait macro
>   `BOOST_IS_ABSTRACT(T)` to do this. Not
>   all compilers support this type trait
>   and corresponding macro. To address
>   this, the macro
>   `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(T)`
>   has been implemented to permit one to
>   explicitly indicate that a specified
>   type is in fact abstract. This will
>   guarentee that `BOOST_IS_ABSTRACT` will
>   return the correct value for all
>   compilers.

However, your problem seems related to:

```
namespace boost { 
namespace serialization {
template<class T>
struct is_wrapper
 : public mpl::false_
{};
} // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost
```

> For any class T, The default
>   definition of
>   boost::serialization::is_wrapper::value
>   is thus false.

I would try explicitly specializing `boost::serialization::is_wrapper<BaseTable>`.  After all, you are serializing through a pointer to the base.

Finally, your base (BaseTable) may need a serialize method (but maybe not; boost::serialization does some nifty typeid magic); I'm not sure why you have an empty save and load in it at all.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you're still interested in this problem, but I think the problem is that you're not specifying a nvp (Name-Value Pair) for the base class in your serialize() function.

There is a macro for that:

```
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(my_base_class)
```

Check http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html#nvp.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error message in Visual Studio 2008.  Oddly enough, I solved the issue by removing a `const` from in front of the variable being serialized (I had pasted it in by mistake).  See below:

```
template<class Archive>
inline void load_construct_data(Archive & ar, myClass * t, const unsigned int file_version)
{
    const std::map<std::wstring, std::wstring> data;
    ar >> _data;

    ::new(t)myClass(_data);
}
```

the above should have the first line in the function replaced by:

```
std::map<std::wstring, std::wstring> data;
```

I don't know how why this would cause the same error message, but I hope this helps someone.